# In Blender, my character doesnt come with bones in fbx format

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

In Blender, I am currently using a panda bear from the link https://3docean.net/item/cartoon-panda-rigged/21749155. I inserted the Panda Bear model in Blender as an FBX and I added the texture in. But when I went into wireframe mode I didn't see any bones in that Panda Bear, I'm trying to see if the Panda Bear can move with the bones that are in the Panda bear. However there aren't any bones in the Panda Bear. Please help

Comment: Since you appear to have to  register and pay for the model when downloading it there's no way we can see it. However the details say "In Max version only: the model is rigged ( pelvis, head, legs, arms, hands, spine, head, foot, fingers mouth)." I assume this means that the export format files don't include rigging.

Comment: oh Sorry about that